# Bernoulli parameter estimation after every sample received

Tags: sampling, sample-size, bernoulli-distribution, online-algorithms

I have a pretty simply-looking question on the parameter estimation. hope you can help me.

I have a biased coin and I want to decide if the probability of head $p$ is bigger or smaller than  known probability $p_0$ (and this I want to guess correctly with high probability, say  99%).

If I draw say $100$ samples, it is easy to compute the confidence intervals and decide or abstain. However, I don't want to decide on the number of samples beforhand, but rather want to draw just enough samples to be able to decide if $p > p_0$ or not. I can compute the confidence intervals after every sample, however it is not correct because the "prefixes" of sampled sequence are not independednt, thus, my predetermined confidence level is "poisoned".

The motivation is quite natural. If I toss the coin $100$ times and receive $100$ heads, then I can guarantee that $p > 0.5$ (with failure probability 1%) and it makes no sense to draw further. On the other hand, if $p \approx p_0$, I may need a lot more samples.

Unfortunatelly, I don't think there is a perfect universal answer, so I'm happy for any partial thougths.

Comment: It sounds like you want a [Sequential Probability Ratio Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_probability_ratio_test).  The meaning of "draw enough samples" is ambiguous, though.  You can design sampling programs to minimize the expected number of draws for a particular alternative hypothesis about $p,$ or you can try to achieve some other measure of the sampling burden.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks like something I need, although I haven't understood it yet.

And I'm not sure if I understand the ambiguity. I thought that given a sequence of K mesaurements, I can decide that they are enough to claim p > p_0 with high probability, or I need another sample. But this is probably dependent on the statistical procedure I will use, so If I understand it correctly, there is no distribution-less way to describe it.

Comment: The ambiguity lies in the meaning of "draw just enough samples" and that (therefore) leads to various solutions, depending on additional assumptions you make and other constraints you might need to apply (such as setting an absolute upper threshold on the sample size along with your power requirements).

Comment: For the simplicity I would assume no upper threshold. I fail to see different meanings, could you please provide them? In simple words, I want to receive new samples until I can answer the question if p >= p_0 or not with 99% certainty.

Comment: The problem is that you might never reach a decision and your sampling might never terminate.  That's usually considered a bad thing!  Thus, *at the very minimum,* such sampling programs include additional termination criteria.  Moreover, if you are confident $p$ is far from $p_0$ you might be able to end the sampling and make a decision sooner than otherwise, showing how vague the meaning of "just enough samples" might be.

Comment: yes, I meant it in the way that after every sample I decide if I want to receive another one (which is exactly the setting SPRT considers). Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you approach this in a Bayesian way?

Place a beta prior on $p$, and then toss the coin repeatedly. After each toss, the posterior is updated and you check the amount of posterior probability for values above $p_0$.

Here is some rough code. I am assuming that p > p0, and using p0 = 0.5.

```
# reference value
p0 <- 0.5

# biased prob of head
p <- runif(n = 1L, min = p0, max = 1)

# threshold on posterior prob that p > p0
prob_threshold <- 0.99

heads <- 1L
tails <- 1L

for(i in 1:100){
  # new coin toss
  x <- rbinom(n = 1L, size = 1L, prob = p)

  # update counts
  if(x == 0L){
    tails <- tails + 1L
  }else{
    heads <- heads + 1L
  }

  # quantify the posterior prob above the reference value
  z <- pbeta(p0, shape1 = heads, shape2 = tails, lower.tail = FALSE)

  if(z >= prob_threshold){
    break
  }
}
```

As @whuber points out, you probably want some additional termination criterion. Here, I run at most 100 trials for example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that this way, the test will not be as significant as I want. The problem is that the "quantify the posterior prob above the reference value" part is done after every received sample. Thus, In every iteration, we have 1% chance of failure but we want 1% in total. It seems to be related to a term "alpha spending" that I just learned.
.

Comment: In fact, I run a similar code to yours (my p0 = p = 0.7), I ran 1000 samples. The correct behaviour would be to not say p > p0, nor p < p0. If I do the confidence intervals after 1000 samples received (I set failure probability to 0.05) - it told me in 42/1000 cases that either p > p0 or the other way round - which is cca expected. On the other hand, if I computed confidence intervals after every sample, I would in 391/1000 cases answer that p >p0 or p < p0.

Thanks anyway!